# Print each servername line by line from specified column in CSV file using Powershell

Tags: powershell, loops, csv

I am creating a powershell script which compares the memory usage percent to a predefined number.

Based on the outcome of this, a line will be printed detailing whether the memory usage is below or above the predefined number.

I am having problems trying to get each servername printed row by row from a specific column into a DAT file.

## My Powershell script:

```
$day = Get-Date -format dd
$Dir = "C:\test\output"
$file = "$Dir\result_esxhost_memory_check2.dat"
$location = "C:\test\output"
$FileExist =  Test-Path -Path $location
$date = Get-Date -format "dd.MM.yy HH:mm"


#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#Declaring variables which stores a value from a selected column in the CSV file
#
#
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
$memoryusage = Import-Csv -Path C:\test\log\checks2.csv | select -ExpandProperty MemoryUsage
$name = Import-Csv -Path "C:\test\log\checks2.csv" | select -ExpandProperty Name -First 1




#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Clear-Content "$file"

  
    
    foreach ($row in $memoryusage) {

    
    If ( "$row" -lt [int32]"45") {
        $Line = "$name" + "|" + $date + "|MemoryUsage|NONE|OK|Memory usage of ESX Host $name is below the threshold" + " " + "($row)" }
    else {
        $Line = "$name" + "|" + $date + "|MemoryUsage|NONE|WARNING|Memory usage of ESX Host $name is above the threshold" + " " + "($row)"}


         Add-Content "$file" `n$Line
                $in = [System.IO.File]::OpenText($file)
$text = ($in.readtoend()).trim("`n")
$in.close()

$stream = [System.IO.StreamWriter]$file
$stream.write($text)
$stream.close()  
   
         
   
    }
```

## When the script is run, the results in the DAT file shows as follows:

```
Server1|21.03.23 12:46|MemoryUsage|NONE|OK|Memory usage of ESX Host Server1 is below the threshold (33.14%)
Server1|21.03.23 12:46|MemoryUsage|NONE|OK|Memory usage of ESX Host Server1 is below the threshold (25.23%)
Server1|21.03.23 12:46|MemoryUsage|NONE|WARNING|Memory usage of ESX Host Server1 is above the threshold (54.23%)
Server1|21.03.23 12:46|MemoryUsage|NONE|OK|Memory usage of ESX Host Server1 is below the threshold (37.57%)
Server1|21.03.23 12:46|MemoryUsage|NONE|WARNING|Memory usage of ESX Host Server1 is above the threshold (46.76%)
Server1|21.03.23 12:46|MemoryUsage|NONE|WARNING|Memory usage of ESX Host Server1 is above the threshold (48.94%)
Server1|21.03.23 12:46|MemoryUsage|NONE|WARNING|Memory usage of ESX Host Server1 is above the threshold (61.30%)
Server1|21.03.23 12:46|MemoryUsage|NONE|OK|Memory usage of ESX Host Server1 is below the threshold (43.27%)
Server1|21.03.23 12:46|MemoryUsage|NONE|WARNING|Memory usage of ESX Host Server1 is above the threshold (52.16%)
Server1|21.03.23 12:46|MemoryUsage|NONE|OK|Memory usage of ESX Host Server1 is below the threshold (1.74%)
Server1|21.03.23 12:46|MemoryUsage|NONE|OK|Memory usage of ESX Host Server1 is below the threshold (1.78%)
Server1|21.03.23 12:46|MemoryUsage|NONE|OK|Memory usage of ESX Host Server1 is below the threshold (26.95%)
Server1|21.03.23 12:46|MemoryUsage|NONE|OK|Memory usage of ESX Host Server1 is below the threshold (39.59%)
Server1|21.03.23 12:46|MemoryUsage|NONE|OK|Memory usage of ESX Host Server1 is below the threshold (1.89%)
Server1|21.03.23 12:46|MemoryUsage|NONE|OK|Memory usage of ESX Host Server1 is below the threshold (39.40%)
Server1|21.03.23 12:46|MemoryUsage|NONE|OK|Memory usage of ESX Host Server1 is below the threshold (33.16%)
Server1|21.03.23 12:46|MemoryUsage|NONE|OK|Memory usage of ESX Host Server1 is below the threshold (1.90%)
Server1|21.03.23 12:46|MemoryUsage|NONE|OK|Memory usage of ESX Host Server1 is below the threshold (23.37%)
Server1|21.03.23 12:46|MemoryUsage|NONE|OK|Memory usage of ESX Host Server1 is below the threshold (23.73%)
Server1|21.03.23 12:46|MemoryUsage|NONE|OK|Memory usage of ESX Host Server1 is below the threshold (25.26%)
Server1|21.03.23 12:46|MemoryUsage|NONE|OK|Memory usage of ESX Host Server1 is below the threshold (12.39%)
Server1|21.03.23 12:46|MemoryUsage|NONE|OK|Memory usage of ESX Host Server1 is below the threshold (44.62%)
Server1|21.03.23 12:46|MemoryUsage|NONE|OK|Memory usage of ESX Host Server1 is below the threshold (23.60%)
Server1|21.03.23 12:46|MemoryUsage|NONE|OK|Memory usage of ESX Host Server1 is below the threshold (12.82%)
Server1|21.03.23 12:46|MemoryUsage|NONE|OK|Memory usage of ESX Host Server1 is below the threshold (12.84%)
Server1|21.03.23 12:46|MemoryUsage|NONE|WARNING|Memory usage of ESX Host Server1 is above the threshold (75.82%)
Server1|21.03.23 12:46|MemoryUsage|NONE|WARNING|Memory usage of ESX Host Server1 is above the threshold (73.86%)
Server1|21.03.23 12:46|MemoryUsage|NONE|WARNING|Memory usage of ESX Host Server1 is above the threshold (57.83%)
Server1|21.03.23 12:46|MemoryUsage|NONE|OK|Memory usage of ESX Host Server1 is below the threshold (1.77%)
Server1|21.03.23 12:46|MemoryUsage|NONE|WARNING|Memory usage of ESX Host Server1 is above the threshold (6.30%)
Server1|21.03.23 12:46|MemoryUsage|NONE|OK|Memory usage of ESX Host Server1 is below the threshold (11.74%)
Server1|21.03.23 12:46|MemoryUsage|NONE|OK|Memory usage of ESX Host Server1 is below the threshold (21.01%)
Server1|21.03.23 12:46|MemoryUsage|NONE|OK|Memory usage of ESX Host Server1 is below the threshold (18.65%)
Server1|21.03.23 12:46|MemoryUsage|NONE|OK|Memory usage of ESX Host Server1 is below the threshold (28.65%)
Server1|21.03.23 12:46|MemoryUsage|NONE|OK|Memory usage of ESX Host Server1 is below the threshold (22.22%)
Server1|21.03.23 12:46|MemoryUsage|NONE|OK|Memory usage of ESX Host Server1 is below the threshold (1.88%)
Server1|21.03.23 12:46|MemoryUsage|NONE|OK|Memory usage of ESX Host Server1 is below the threshold (23.21%)
Server1|21.03.23 12:46|MemoryUsage|NONE|OK|Memory usage of ESX Host Server1 is below the threshold (12.36%)
Server1|21.03.23 12:46|MemoryUsage|NONE|OK|Memory usage of ESX Host Server1 is below the threshold (23.45%)
Server1|21.03.23 12:46|MemoryUsage|NONE|OK|Memory usage of ESX Host Server1 is below the threshold (23.83%)
Server1|21.03.23 12:46|MemoryUsage|NONE|OK|Memory usage of ESX Host Server1 is below the threshold (23.63%)
Server1|21.03.23 12:46|MemoryUsage|NONE|OK|Memory usage of ESX Host Server1 is below the threshold (14.96%)
Server1|21.03.23 12:46|MemoryUsage|NONE|OK|Memory usage of ESX Host Server1 is below the threshold (16.05%)
Server1|21.03.23 12:46|MemoryUsage|NONE|OK|Memory usage of ESX Host Server1 is below the threshold (15.25%)
```

PLEASE NOTE: I only added the -First 1 to end of the $name variable to keep the data tidy, as it will simply add EVERY server name from each row of the "Name" column in the CSV file on EACH line in the DAT file.

## The CSV file looks like this:

```
"Name","ConnectionState","PowerState","CpuUsage","MemoryUsage","Version"
"Server1","Connected","PoweredOn","2.64%","33.14%","7.0.3"
"Server2","Connected","PoweredOn","1.85%","25.23%","7.0.3"
"Server3","Connected","PoweredOn","10.99%","54.23%","7.0.3"
"Server2esx401","Connected","PoweredOn","8.95%","37.57%","7.0.3"
"Server2esx402","Connected","PoweredOn","3.96%","46.76%","7.0.3"
"Server1esx403","Connected","PoweredOn","18.66%","48.94%","7.0.3"
"Server1esx402","Connected","PoweredOn","27.51%","61.30%","7.0.3"
"Server1esx401","Connected","PoweredOn","21.83%","43.27%","7.0.3"
"Server1esx502","Connected","PoweredOn","6.74%","52.16%","7.0.3"
"Server1esx503","Connected","PoweredOn","0.15%","1.74%","7.0.3"
"Server1esx505","Connected","PoweredOn","0.31%","1.78%","7.0.3"
"Server1esx501","Connected","PoweredOn","2.01%","26.95%","7.0.3"
"Server1esx504","Connected","PoweredOn","4.28%","39.59%","7.0.3"
"Server1esx802","Connected","PoweredOn","0.21%","1.89%","7.0.3"
"Server1esx803","Connected","PoweredOn","2.67%","39.40%","7.0.3"
"Server1esx801","Connected","PoweredOn","1.35%","33.16%","7.0.3"
"Server1esx804","Connected","PoweredOn","0.17%","1.90%","7.0.3"
"Server1esx406","Connected","PoweredOn","1.67%","23.37%","7.0.3"
"Server1esx405","Connected","PoweredOn","1.80%","23.73%","7.0.3"
"Server1esx404","Connected","PoweredOn","1.17%","25.26%","7.0.3"
"Server1esx302","Connected","PoweredOn","0.74%","12.39%","7.0.3"
"Server1esx305","Connected","PoweredOn","1.14%","44.62%","7.0.3"
"Server1esx301","Connected","PoweredOn","1.11%","23.60%","7.0.3"
"Server1esx303","Connected","PoweredOn","0.53%","12.82%","7.0.3"
"Server1esx304","Connected","PoweredOn","0.46%","12.84%","7.0.3"
"Server1esx902","Connected","PoweredOn","12.35%","75.82%","7.0.3"
"Server1esx901","Connected","PoweredOn","28.83%","73.86%","7.0.3"
"Server2esx501","Connected","PoweredOn","5.19%","57.83%","7.0.3"
"Server2esx503","Connected","PoweredOn","0.17%","1.77%","7.0.3"
"Server2esx502","Connected","PoweredOn","1.65%","6.30%","7.0.3"
"Server2esx505","Connected","PoweredOn","2.31%","11.74%","7.0.3"
"Server2esx504","Connected","PoweredOn","2.11%","21.01%","7.0.3"
"Server2esx804","Connected","PoweredOn","1.40%","18.65%","7.0.3"
"Server2esx802","Connected","PoweredOn","2.30%","28.65%","7.0.3"
"Server2esx801","Connected","PoweredOn","1.46%","22.22%","7.0.3"
"Server2esx803","Connected","PoweredOn","0.39%","1.88%","7.0.3"
"Server2esx301","Connected","PoweredOn","1.68%","23.21%","7.0.3"
"Server2esx304","Connected","PoweredOn","0.32%","12.36%","7.0.3"
"Server2esx302","Connected","PoweredOn","1.55%","23.45%","7.0.3"
"Server2esx303","Connected","PoweredOn","0.37%","23.83%","7.0.3"
"Server2esx305","Connected","PoweredOn","0.94%","23.63%","7.0.3"
"Server2esx406","Connected","PoweredOn","1.10%","14.96%","7.0.3"
"Server2esx405","Connected","PoweredOn","1.02%","16.05%","7.0.3"
"Server2esx404","Connected","PoweredOn","0.97%","15.25%","7.0.3"
```

So to conclude, I would like the DAT file to show each servername from the "Name" column of the CSV file line by line.

## An example of the output I am looking for:

```
Server1|21.03.23 12:46|MemoryUsage|NONE|OK|Memory usage of ESX Host Server1 is below the threshold (33.14%)
Server2|21.03.23 12:46|MemoryUsage|NONE|OK|Memory usage of ESX Host Server2 is below the threshold (25.23%)
Server3|21.03.23 12:46|MemoryUsage|NONE|WARNING|Memory usage of ESX Host Server3 is above the threshold (54.23%)
Server2esx401|21.03.23 12:46|MemoryUsage|NONE|OK|Memory usage of ESX Host Server2esx401 is below the threshold (37.57%)
Server2esx403|21.03.23 12:46|MemoryUsage|NONE|WARNING|Memory usage of ESX Host Server2esx403 is above the threshold (46.76%)
Server1esx403|21.03.23 12:46|MemoryUsage|NONE|WARNING|Memory usage of ESX Host Server1esx403 is above the threshold (48.94%)
Server1esx402|21.03.23 12:46|MemoryUsage|NONE|WARNING|Memory usage of ESX Host Server1esx402 is above the threshold (61.30%)
```

Hopefully, that explains what I am looking for.

Thank you, and much appreciated for any help!

Mike

Comment: After Import-CSV you want to sort object by server name.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object?force_isolation=true&view=powershell-7.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that you are getting all of the server names on each line is that your $name variable is a collection. It is the entire contents of the "name" column from your CSV. So when you put that variable into a string, it puts the entire set of server names in.

First, you can simplify how you import the CSV. Given what you are trying to do, you do not need two imports, and you do not need to use the `-ExpandProperty` flag.

Simply using `$csvData = Import-Csv -Path "YourPath"` is enough for you to get the entire CSV into an object, where the CSV column names are now object property names. If you just want the name and memoryUsage from the CSV then you can do this:

```
$csvData = Import-CSV -Path "YourPath" | Select-Object -Property Name, MemoryUsage
```

By not using `-ExpandProperty` the resulting $csvData object will contain named properties, making them easier to reference in a loop.

Finally we can build the desired string:

```
ForEach($row in $csvData){
   #skipping the conditional logic for clarity
   $line = $row.name + '|' + $date + '|' + $row.MemoryUsage + etc...
}
```

As a side note, I prefer to use a more explicit form of string concatenation. This certainly isn't a standard, but I like the way it looks:

```
$line = [string]::concat($row.Name, '|', $date, '|MemoryUsage|NONE|OK|Memory usage of ESX Host ', $row.Name, ' is below the threshold ', $row.MemoryUsage)
```